# How to always hide a subtree in org mode?

Tags: org-mode

Is there a property or command that can help to hide/fold a subtree temporarily even when doing `org-cycle`?

Comment: You can modify `org-cycle-hide-drawers` to skip over something you have hidden that contains a special property/symbol; e.g., an overlay property such as `'org-cycle--skip-this t`.  However, there are only a very few Emacs users in the world who would dare modify a stock function -- e.g., I modify the heck out of anything and everything that I can get my hands on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you mark the heading as "archived" then it's ignored for the default visibility toggling.

`C-c C-x a` (`org-toggle-archive-tag`), which just adds/removes the "ARCHIVE" tag to the heading -- all the subtree content remains.

Even when marked as archived you can force expansion with `C-c C-TAB` (`org-force-cycle-archived`) on the heading if you want, or just remove the archive tag.

note: if you're using a version of Emacs older than 27 then the binding is `C-TAB` (this binding was appropriated for tab-bar-mode in Emacs 27 and thus had to change).

See the manual for more details: https://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-archiving.html#Internal-archiving

edit: added note about changed keybinding for `org-force-cycle-archived` from Emacs 27.

Comment: Just...fantastic!

Comment: You're welcome!